# Error deploying Microsoft System CLR Types per SQL Server witch ClickOnce

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, clickonce, reportviewer, sqlclr

I'm trying to deploy an application that uses `Microsoft ReportViewer 2012` that needs `Microsoft® System CLR Types per SQL Server 2012` in order to work but I can't get to install it with ClickOnce.

I checked them in project's prerequisites but it seems they cannot be found 
(I checked download from the web).

[image]

even if they're present in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages
```

[image]

[image]

When I deploy my setup installation fail because it can't download SqlClrTypes. If I install them using the same msi manually it works ok.

What can I do to make them install via ClickOnce ? 
I'm using Visual Studio 2017, tried 2019 but the same thing happen.

EDIT: Fixed the issue with the prerequisites, my product.xml was referring to the wrong version for some reason. Now the setup is created without issue but when I try the installation it fails when downloading the msi. From the install.log it tries to download it from : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=221258